# Using df.name.str.replace with backreference

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with alphanumeric labels that doesn't sort well, that looks something like this:

```
    Timestamp   
11019   MAR_H15 
11020   MAR_H16 
11021   JAN_H19
```

I'm trying to replace the month prefix with the number equivalent to make it sort well. I'm using the following:

```
from datetime import datetime as d
def f(match):
    return d.strptime(match, '%b').month

df['Timestamp'] = df.Timestamp.str.replace(r'(^[A-Z]{3})',f,regex=True)
```

I keep getting the following error.

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

What's the proper way to use stuff a backreferenced value into a function?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: your value in timestamp type. .str is working on only str values. try to convert the timestamp column to string type

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert column to string (because there has to be some another values, I guess numeric) and select first 3 values by indexing `str[:3]`, then convert to datetimes with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and `errros='coerce'` for `NaT` if no match `%b` and last convert to months (for missing values are returned `NaN`s):

```
s = df.Timestamp.astype(str).str[:3]
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%b', errors='coerce').dt.month
print (df)
       Timestamp
11019          3
11020          3
11021          1
```

**Details**:

```
s = df.Timestamp.astype(str).str[:3]
print (s)
11019    MAR
11020    MAR
11021    JAN
Name: Timestamp, dtype: object
```

---

```
print (df)
      Timestamp
11019   MAR_H15
11020   MAR_H16
11021   JAN_H19
11021       123

s = df.Timestamp.astype(str).str[:3]
print (s)
11019    MAR
11020    MAR
11021    JAN
11021    123
Name: Timestamp, dtype: object

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%b', errors='coerce').dt.month
print (df)
       Timestamp
11019        3.0
11020        3.0
11021        1.0
11021        NaN
```